# Linked list in function

Tags: c, list, function, linked-list

I want to write a c code, in which there are some parameters whose length are not defined and may be changed during the code. So I understood that I have to use linked List for these kind of variables. 
The problem is that I do not know how to declare them as an argument for function. For example we use "int" for integer variables. how can I declare a list.

Please, give an example to define a list and use them in a function (just the first line of function).
Please consider that I am using the following declaration type for linked list

```
typedef struct node_type{
    int data;
    struct node_type *next;
    } node;
typedef node *list;
```

Thank you

Comment: refer http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Answer (score 1):

You can assign memory to node of list as

```
node *ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You can pass node of list in function as

```
some_function(&ptr);
```

And function definition as

```
void some_function(node **pointer)
```

Comment: Thank you actually I define linked list as follows:
typedef struct node_type{
    int data;
    struct node_type *next;
    } node;
typedef node *list;

How can I use it in this format